# Usercontrol Binding inside Itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

Edit2 if anyone is interested.
This is how i fixed the Problem (sadly not really mvvm but the binding did not work somehow if the datagrid was inside an itemscontrol)

```
        public ObservableCollection<int> SelectedCells
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<int>)GetValue(SelectedCellsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedCellsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedCellsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                "SelectedCells",
                                                typeof(ObservableCollection<int>),
                                                typeof(DataGrid),
                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, SelectedCellsChanged));

    private static void SelectedCellsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as DataGrid;
        control?.RaiseSelectedCellsChangedEvent(e.OldValue, e.NewValue);
    }

    public event RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object> SelectedCellsChangedEvent;
    public void RaiseSelectedCellsChangedEvent(object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        SelectedCellsChangedEvent?.Invoke(this, new RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object>(oldValue, newValue));
    }
```

In The mainView:

```
                    <uc:DataGrid Height="160" Width="300" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             DataGridSource="{Binding}"
                             Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                             SelectedCellsChangedEvent="DataGrid_SelectedCellsChangedEvent"
```

code behind mainwindow:

```
        private void DataGrid_SelectedCellsChangedEvent(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {

        ObservableCollection<int> newValue = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<int>;
    }
```

Edit:

The PropertyChangedCallback Function is getting called, but the problem is that it is only not working if the binding is inside my itemscontrol.
If the <uc:datagrid> is not inside an itemscontrol it is working!

```
        public ObservableCollection<int> SelectedCells
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<int>)GetValue(SelectedCellsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedCellsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedCellsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedCells", typeof(ObservableCollection<int>), typeof(DataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedCellsChanged)));

    private static void OnSelectedCellsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This method will be called whenever the value of the SelectedCells property changes
        // You can perform any additional logic you need to here
        Console.WriteLine("change"); <-- This is getting called, also if in my itemscontrol
    }
```

I have a problem with the binding inside of an Itemscontrol.

I want to know which cells are currently selected in my Datagrid(inside a usercontrol).

This is my Datagrid Usercontrol.
Here I added a Dependency Property SelectedCells.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for DataGrid.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class DataGrid : UserControl
{
    public DataGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SelectedCells = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    }

    public DataGridValue DataGridSource
    {
        get { return (DataGridValue)GetValue(DataGridSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataGridSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataGridSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DataGridSource", typeof(DataGridValue), typeof(DataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public ObservableCollection<int> SelectedCells
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<int>)GetValue(SelectedCellsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedCellsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedCellsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedCells", typeof(ObservableCollection<int>), typeof(DataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    private void datagrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedCells = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        foreach (DataGridCellInfo cellInfo in datagrid.SelectedCells)
        {
            int columnIndex = cellInfo.Column.DisplayIndex;
            int rowIndex = datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(
                datagrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cellInfo.Item));
            //Console.WriteLine($"Cell ({rowIndex}, {columnIndex}) is selected.");

            switch((DayName)columnIndex)
            {
                case 0: break;
                case DayName.Mo: 
                    if (DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].MondayCell.Text != string.Empty)
                    {
                        SelectedCells.Add(Convert.ToInt32(DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].MondayCell.Text));
                    }
                    break;
                case DayName.Di:
                    if (DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].TuesdayCell.Text != string.Empty)
                    {
                        SelectedCells.Add(Convert.ToInt32(DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].TuesdayCell.Text));
                    }
                    break;
                case DayName.Mi:
                    if (DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].WednesdayCell.Text != string.Empty)
                    {
                        SelectedCells.Add(Convert.ToInt32(DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].WednesdayCell.Text));
                    }
                    break;
                case DayName.Do:
                    if (DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].ThursdayCell.Text != string.Empty)
                    {
                        SelectedCells.Add(Convert.ToInt32(DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].ThursdayCell.Text));
                    }
                    break;
                case DayName.Fr:
                    if (DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].FridayCell.Text != string.Empty)
                    {
                        SelectedCells.Add(Convert.ToInt32(DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].FridayCell.Text));
                    }
                    break;
                case DayName.Sa:
                    if (DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].SaturdayCell.Text != string.Empty)
                    {
                        SelectedCells.Add(Convert.ToInt32(DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].SaturdayCell.Text));
                    }
                    break;
                case DayName.So:
                    if (DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].SundayCell.Text != string.Empty)
                    {
                        SelectedCells.Add(Convert.ToInt32(DataGridSource.DataGridList[rowIndex].SundayCell.Text));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

        <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid"
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          SelectionUnit="Cell"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          Background="Transparent"
          BorderBrush="Transparent"
          SelectedCellsChanged="datagrid_SelectedCellsChanged"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DataGridSource.DataGridList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
          >
```

If I just add my DataGrid to my mainView the binding is working:

```
<uc:DataGrid Height="160" Width="300" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             DataGridSource="{Binding TestGrid}"
                             SelectedCells="{Binding TestList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             Margin="20,20,0,0"/>
```

property:

```
    public partial class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<int> testList;
    public ObservableCollection<int> TestList
    {
        get
        {
            if (testList == null)
            {
                testList = new ObservableCollection<int>();
            }
            return testList;
        }
        set
        {
            testList = value;
        }
    }
```

But if I am doing this Inside of an Itemscontrol the binding is not working.
I want it to bind to the Property inside of my MainViewModel.
In the debugger there are no binding issues, but the setter is never called.

This is my Itemscontrol:

```
<ItemsControl Name="MyItemsControl" Visibility="Visible"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataGridSelectedYear, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                  Margin="0,55,0,0">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <uc:DataGrid Height="160" Width="300" 
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             DataGridSource="{Binding}"
                             Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                             SelectedCells="{Binding DataContext.TestList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                             Margin="20,20,0,0">
                    <uc:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Test" 
                                      Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AddBackColorCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                      />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </uc:DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                </uc:DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

But it also does not work if I add the property to my class where the Itemscontrol does get it’s data from (DataGridSelectedYear). Also no Binding errors in the debugger but the setter never gets called.

Comment: Sorry, Think I forgot to mention:

SelectedCells="{Binding DataContext.TestList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"

Comment: The setter of `SelectedCells` is not supposed to be called. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The binding engine calls the `SetValue` method of the `DependencyObject` when setting a dependency property so the setter of your `SelectedCells` property is not supposed to be invoked when you bind to a source property.

You could register a [PropertyChangedCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.propertychangedcallback?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) if you want to confirm that the property is set as expected.

Comment: I added this Callback, but how can I then get/set the value via binding?
The function OnSelectedCellsChanged gets called, but from my mainView I do not get the event / the set does not get called.  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedCellsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedCells", typeof(ObservableCollection<int>), typeof(DataGrid), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSelectedCellsChanged)));

        private static void OnSelectedCellsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {Console.WriteLine("change");

Comment: what is also strange, when my uc:datagrid is not in the itemscontrol the binding works as I expect it, only when it is inside the itemscontrol it does not work

Comment: You bind to the property exactly as before. Are you saying that the callback doesn't get triggered?

Comment: The Callback Function is getting triggered. Also when bind inside the itemscontrol. But when inside the itemscontrol I do not get the Value in my mainViewModel TestList.   But when the datagrid is not inside an itemscontrol i get the value to my TestList

Comment: `TestList` is the *source*  property. It's not supposed to get set when you bind.

Comment: Why does it work then if not in the itemscontrol? In my case the TestList should only be there to get the Property of my userControl, not to set it. How would i need to do that?

Comment: Aren't you setting the property in `datagrid_SelectedCellsChanged`?

Comment: Yes, there I am adding something to the List:       SelectedCells.Add(someInteger);

Comment: Even when the control is in the `ItemsControl`?

Comment: when in my itemscontrol, I go in the datagrid_SelectedCellsChanged function and add the integers to the SelectedCells, but you are correct, after adding it the OnSelectCellsChanged does not get called

Comment: So there is no binding then?

Comment: it does not seem like it. after the datagrid_SelectedCellsChanged the list is filled correctly, but I'm not sure why it is not binding